# Jquery First occurrence tree traversal up parents/siblings

Tags: jquery, tree, siblings, parents

What is the best way to get closest (up tree) given a class, but it can be a sibling of a parent.

I want to get "errors1" element start with element ".start"

```
<div>
    ...
    <div class="errors">errors2</div>
    <div>
        .....
        <div class="errors">errors1</div>
        ...
        <div>...</div>
        <div>
            .....
            <div class="start"></div>            
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Made a script but its really bad and doesnt work at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/9DfCJ/1/

Thanks

**EDITED:**
Added "..." to enhance that structure is dynamic. The point is to find the closest ".errors" up tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. The code below should work for you. It loops over each parent of `.start` until it finds an element with `.errors`. Then it alerts the text of the `.errors` element that is closest to `.start`.

```
jQuery(function($){

    var $start = $('.start'),
        $parents = $start.parents();

    $parents.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $thisErrors = $this.find('.errors'),
            numErrors = $thisErrors.length;

        if(numErrors){
            alert($thisErrors.eq(numErrors-1).text());
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I guess it's better that you replace the find selector for '.errors:not(.start .errors)' to avoid getting .errors element that is descendant of the .start or if the start element is hard to be selected with a selector add jQuery.contains($start, $errorsMatchElement) validation before returning with a match.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate jQuery's `prev()` command. For example, to find and hide the previous 'errors' when in the context of the 'start' class, you would use the following:

```
$('.start').click(function(){
  $(this).prev('.errors').hide();
});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

**UPDATE:**

You may have better luck using `parent()` to traverse upward if it is heavily nested. `parent()` also takes a selector as an argument... without an argument it grabs the parent of the current node.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().siblings(':first')
```

Comment: He's looking for a way to query by the class from the parent. In this case `$(this).parent('.errors')`;

Comment: i forgot to say that the structure may vary. The point is to achieve the closest ".errors" in the tree

Answer (score 1):

A function to return the item as a jQuery object so it is more reusable.

This is more efficient than Byran's answer because it only looks at one level at a time rather than loading all parents and checking all levels of children via find (http://api.jquery.com/find/) each time.

To use, just paste the function into your javascript file or script tags after jQuery has been loaded.

```
$('.start').closestParentsAndSibling( '.errors').html('found!');

(function( $ ){
   $.fn.closestParentsAndSibling = function(search) {
        // Get the current element's siblings
        var siblings = this.siblings(search);

        if (siblings.length != 0) { // Did we get a hit?
            return siblings.eq(0);
        }

        // Traverse up another level
        var parent = this.parent();
        if (parent === undefined || parent.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() == 'body') {
            // We reached the body tag or failed to get a parent with no result.
            // Return the empty siblings tag so as to return an empty jQuery object.
            return siblings;
        }
        // Try again
        return parent.closestParentsAndSibling(search);
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go up the tree, and get all the errors, you could do something like that:

```
var start = $(".start"),
    current = start.parent(),
    parent = current,
    end_class = "stop",
    get_errors = function(elt) {
        return elt.children(".errors");
    },
    errors = get_errors(current)

    while (parent = current.parent()) {

        $.merge(errors, get_errors(parent));
        if (parent.hasClass(end_class)) {
           break;
        }   
        current = parent;
    }
```

At the end, `errors` will contain all the errors.

You would have to add the `end_class` to your top div though.

```
<div class="stop">
    ...
    <div class="errors">errors2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and found something to get the first element that that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up :

```
var myText = $(".start").closest($(".errors")).text();
```

read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and you can use your event to call this code.